# metric spaces: clarification on Open and Closed sets.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

just a quick question for my own clarification.

Consider the metric space $(X,d)$ with $A \subset X$.

we know $A \subset_{closed} X$ if $A$ is finite, or $\forall$ infinite sequence $x_n \in A ~ \exists ~x \in A$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$
then for visualisation purposes does this mean that the only instance (putting open & closed sets to the side for the moment) that $A \subset_{open} X$ is if there exists a divergent infinite sequence in A?

i know A is open if $Int(A) = A$ (also the requirements for $x \in Int(A)$) and this implies $X \setminus A$ is closed. Further the above suggests that $X \setminus A$ can be either finite or infinite, but surely $Int(A)$ must be infinite?

anyone able to give some wise words which might make sense of this?

thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of closed is wrong (you're suggesting that all sequences from $A$ actually converge). If you want a sequence-based definition:

$A$ is closed iff for all sequences $(x_n)$ in $X$ (so these are just functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$, they could be constant, or whatever you please) such that $x_n \in A$ for all $n$ **and if** $x_n \to x$ (in $X$), **then** $x \in A$. So it says nothing about there being any non-trivial convergent sequences in $A$, but that **if** they exist their limit must belong to $A$ as well: informally, you cannot converge to a non-$A$ point with just sequence points from $A$.

This works in metric spaces and general spaces "like it" (so-called sequential spaces).

Being open has a comparable equivalent definition (in metric or similar spaces) in terms of sequences as well: $O$ is open iff for all $x \in O$, and **if** a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ converges to $x$, all but at most finitely many $x_n$ must lie in $O$ as well (i.e. the set $\{n: x_n \notin O\}$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$). No info on divergent sequences, but a conditional statement about sequences that *do* converge, just as for closed sets.